# create DOM header with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, header, createelement

I was messing with Javascript and was trying to create a simple header.
I get no errors, just a simple blank screen.
For a simple document.createElement(), this is getting frustrating.
I got a ul going in the example, but the header is not work

```
var options = [
        set0 = ['Option 1','Option 2'],
        set1 = ['First Option','Second Option','Third Option']
    ];

function makeh1() {
    //header
    var header = document.createElement('h1');
    header.appendChild("Today's News");
    return header;
}

function makeUL(array) {
    // Create the list element:
    var list = document.createElement('ul');

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Create the list item:
        var item = document.createElement('li');

        // Set its contents:
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));

        // Add it to the list:
        list.appendChild(item);
    }

    // Finally, return the constructed list:
    return list;
}
//makeheader
document.getElementById('foo').appendChild(makeh1));
document.getElementById('foo').appendChild(makeUL(options[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = [
    {set : ['Option 1','Option 2']},
    {set : ['First Option','Second Option','Third Option']}
];

function makeh1() {
//header
var header = document.createElement('h1');
header.append("Today's News");
return header;
}



function makeUL(array) {
// Create the list element:
var list = document.createElement('ul');

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // Create the list item:
    var item = document.createElement('li');

    // Set its contents:
    item.append(document.createTextNode(array[i]));

    // Add it to the list:
    list.appendChild(item);
}

// Finally, return the constructed list:
return list;
}
//makeheader
document.getElementById('foo').appendChild(makeh1());
document.getElementById('foo').appendChild(makeUL(options[0].set));
```

your code must change to this

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to something like this.

```js
function makeh1() {
  //header
  var header = document.createElement('h1');
  var text = document.createTextNode("Todays News")
  header.appendChild(text);
  return header;
}
```

```js
document.getElementById('app').appendChild(makeh1())
```